# while accepting socket connection

Tags: c++

```
unsigned __int8 Decrypt(unsigned __int8 data[]);

for(;;)
    {
        if((sConnect=accept(sListen,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,&addrlen)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            Print("Socket Connected Successfully!");
            char buf[4095];
            recv(sListen,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
            Decrypt(buf); // Error:IntelliSense: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char *"

        }
```

how can i fix this prob :-s

Comment: Why not declare buf as type `unsigned __int8[4095]`?

Comment: @James (weird): He might then run into the same compiler complaint in the recv() call.

Comment: @James (why am I the weird one? :P): C-style cast it is then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast buf to unsigned __int8 when you call Decrypt.

```
Decrypt((unsigned __int8*)buf);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use this signature:

```
unsigned char Decrypt(char *data);
```

instead of

```
unsigned __int8 Decrypt(unsigned __int8 data[]);
```

If you do so, you can easily pass `buf` to it, since even though `buf` is declared as `char buf[4095]`, it will become pointer type *automatically* when you pass it to `Decrypt`. No need to cast!

Answer (score 0):

cast it to the correct type.....................................